# fechar div ao clicar fora dela

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma `div` com um `botão` dentro para **fechá-la**. À principio, ela está com `display: none`, mas ao **clicar** em uma botão em outra `div`, ela se transforma em `display: block`.

Preciso arranjar uma forma de quando ela estiver `display: block`, e se por incidente **clicar** em qualquer outra coisa que não seja a `div` (**ou dentro da div**), então, um `click` é disparado no botão que a **fecha**.

Tentei seguinte código:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {       

    alert($("div.peca").css("display"));  //retorna none

    if ( $("div.peca").css("display") === "block" ) {

          alert($("div.peca").css("display"));  //retorna block

          $("div.peca button.fechaPeca").trigger("click");

    }  

});
```

Porém quando eu clico no botão que a torna `display: block`, já vem que ela está `display: block` e então acaba fechando automático.

O que fazer neste caso?

Sei que o **erro** está nessa **linha**:

```
$("div.peca button.fechaPeca").trigger("click");
```

Pois comentei-a e coloquei uma `alert` no lugar e funcionou.

Também tentei:

```
  $("div.peca button.fechaPeca").click();
```

Mesma coisa.

Mas não ideia do porque está ocorrendo este erro. Ou seja, os `botões` param de aceitar `click`

Outro text que fiz foi

```
$(".fechaPeca").on("click", function() {

    $("div.pecaGas").css("display","block");
    $("div.peca").css("display","none");

})
```

substitui por

```
$(".fechaPeca").on("click", function() {

        alert();

})
```

O `alert()` funcionou.

Mas,

```
    $("div.pecaGas").css("display","block");
    $("div.peca").css("display","none");
```

Não funciona quando acesso o

```
    $(".fechaPeca").on("click"
```

Através de outro `click`

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o `e.target` para saber qual o elemento clicado e se ele está dentro do elemento que procuras.

Podes usar o `e.target.closest(seletor)` que sobe no DOM até encontrar um `seletor` CSS. Se não encontrar sabes que está fora desse elemento. Ou então podes ter um elemento e usar o `el.includes(e.target)` que te diz se um dado elemento tem dentro o `e.target`.

Por exemplo:

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  var dentroPeca = e.target.closest('.peca');
  console.log(dentroPeca ? 'Dentro!' : 'Fora!');
});
```

```css
div.peca,
div.outra {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="peca">
  <p>Peça</p>
</div>

<div class="outra">Outra</div>
```

---

Depois de ver o site que referiste nos comentários creio que o que procuras é algo assim: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/0sjc49jf/2/

Porém o problema que tinhas no código é que quando clicas em `.encomende` isso aciona também o `$(document).on('click', function(e) {` e como esse `.encomende` não está dentro de `e.target.closest('div.peca')` acabas por criar um circulo fechado onde a `div.peca` abre e fecha imediatamente.

Por outras palavras:

Quando clicas nesse botão lateral o que corre primeiro é `$(".encomende").on("click"`, aí `div.peca` fica visível. Depois é chamado `$(document).on('click'` que encontra o `div.peca` visível e volta a escondê-lo via `.trigger()`  que funciona. Muda o `if (dentro == null)` para `if (dentro == null && !e.target.classList.contains('encomende'))`.

Ou seja, juntando a condição `!e.target.classList.contains('encomende')` garantes que o `.trigger("click")` não será corrido se `e.target` clicado tiver a classe `encomende`.

Comment: Acho que não entendi muito bem!

Comment: @CarlosRocha dá um salto aqui https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68278/duvidas-seletores para evitar mais comentários aqui que são difíceis de seguir

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer no seguinte esquema:

Inclua neste seletor abaixo os elementos que você não quer que feche a `div` quando clicados (troque a classe `.botaoAbrir` pela classe do elemento que abre a `div`):

```
$(".botaoAbrir, div.peca, div.peca button.fechaPeca").on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

E adicionar um escutador que irá fechar a `div` (se ela estiver visível) quando clicar em qualquer lugar da página, exceto os seletores incluídos no escutador acima:

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
    $("div.peca button.fechaPeca").trigger("click");
});
```

**Teste:**

```js
$(document).on('click',function(){
 $("div.peca button.fechaPeca").trigger("click");
});

$(".botaoAbrir, div.peca, div.peca button.fechaPeca").on('click',function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="peca" style="padding: 20px; color: #fff; display: none; text-align: center; float: left; width: 300px; height: 200px; background: red;">
  Clique fora do box vermelho ou no botão "Fechar" para fechar o box.
  <br />
  <br />
 <button class="fechaPeca" onclick="$('div.peca').hide()">Fechar</button>
</div>

<div>
 <button class="botaoAbrir" onclick="$('div.peca').show()">Abrir</button>
</div>
```